# Starting tasks inside another task is duplicating my WebRequests

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, factory, multitasking

I use the code below to check some pdf files online and return a string accordingly.

The problem is: When I added the second `Task.Factory.StartNew()` it started duplicating all requests, but still returning only one answer(as it should be).

I need this to be as fast as possible so I can't waste time sending two requests to the server.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var listT = new List<string>()
            {
                "24006025062"
            };

            var task = listT.Select(x => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TesteTask(x)));

            Task.WaitAll(task.ToArray(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));

            List<string> results = new List<string>();
            foreach (var result in task)
            {
                results.Add(result.Result);
            }
        }

private static string TesteTask(string codCart)
    {
        var teste = new Consulta();
        var retorno = string.Empty;

        var session = teste.GetCaptcha();


        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            session.CaptchaResolvida = QuebraCaptcha(session.CaptchaCodificada).CaptchaResolvida;
            if (session.CaptchaResolvida.Length > 0)
            {
                var links = teste.Consulta(codCart, session).Retorno;

                if (links.Any())
                {
                    var tasks = links.Select(x => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Executa(teste, session, x)));

                    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));

                    var modelList = from Result in tasks select Result.Result;

                    retorno = teste.FinalizaProcesso(modelList.ToList());

                    break;
                }
            }


        }

        return retorno;
    }

private static string Executa(Consulta teste, Model<Request> session, string link)
    {
        var retorno = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var CaptchaResolvida = QuebraCaptcha(teste.GetCaptchaPdf(session)).CaptchaResolvida;

            if (CaptchaResolvida != null && CaptchaResolvida != string.Empty)
            {
                var status = teste.BaixaPdf(link, CaptchaResolvida, session);

                if (status != string.Empty)
                {
                    retorno = status;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return retorno;
    }
```

Ps: This is my first post on stack overflow, if I'm not clear enough please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this behavior because you are iterating twice on the `Select` returned **IEnumerable**. Try this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var listT = new List<string>()
        {
            "24006025062"
        };

        var task = list
            .Select(x => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TesteTask(x)))
            .ToArray();

        Task.WaitAll(task, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));

        List<string> results = new List<string>();
        foreach (var result in task)
        {
            results.Add(result.Result);
        }
    }
```

By moving the `ToArray()` just after the `Select()` it creates the results **IEnumerable** only once instead of twice.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that.